# How can I insert an XML element between text in the parent element using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I want to generate XML like this:

```
<Element>some text <Child>middle text</Child> some more text</Element>.
```

How can I do this using ElementTree?

I couldn't find it in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). I thought [`element#insert`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25824920/python-elementtree-how-to-add-subelement-at-very-specific-position) would work, but that's for inserting a child in a specific position relative to other children.

Comment: Are you sure you need to generate XML with elementree as opposed to, say, use a template engine, like `mako` or `jinja2` and fill out an XML template? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define the child element and set it's [`.tail`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.tail), then [append](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.append) it to the parent:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


parent = ET.Element("Element")
parent.text = "some text "

child = ET.Element("Child")
child.text = "middle text"
child.tail = " some more text"

parent.append(child)

print(ET.tostring(parent))
```

Prints:

```
<Element>some text <Child>middle text</Child> some more text</Element>
```