# Adding a subelement to the top of subelements with the same tag

Tags: python

In an existing XML file (podcast feed), I am trying to add an element to the top subelements which have the same tag name (item).

The existing XML feed is:

```
<rss xmlns:ns0="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <item>
            <title>Title2</title>
        <\item>
        <item>
            <title>Title3</title>
        <\item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

The python I am using adds the subelement to the bottom of the items.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

parsed_feed=ET.parse('articles.xml')

root = parsed_feed.getroot()

def SubElementWithText(parent, tag, text, attrib):
    element = ET.SubElement(parent, tag, attrib)
    parent.append(element)
    element.text = text
    return element

channel = root.find('channel')
item = ET.SubElement(channel, 'item')
SubElementWithText(item, 'title', 'Title1', attrib={})
```

What I would like to see as a result is:

```
<rss xmlns:ns0="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <item>
            <title>Title1</title>
        <\item>
        <item>
            <title>Title2</title>
        <\item>
        <item>
            <title>Title3</title>
        <\item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25824920/python-elementtree-how-to-add-subelement-at-very-specific-position

Comment: Use insert instead of append.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python ElementTree: How to add SubElement at VERY specific position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25824920/python-elementtree-how-to-add-subelement-at-very-specific-position)

Answer (score 1):

The key was using insert and also Element (instead of SubElement). The insert creates the new item tag. It is then found with find and xpath. From there, the child elements are added.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

parsed_feed=ET.parse('articles.xml')

root = parsed_feed.getroot()

def SubElementWithText(parent, tag, text, attrib):
    element = ET.Element(tag, attrib)
    parent.append(element)
    element.text = text
    return element

channel = root.find('channel')
element = ET.Element('item')
channel.insert(0,element)

item = root.find("./channel/item")

SubElementWithText(item, 'title', 'Title1', attrib={})
```