# Trying to Insert an element in XML using python, but instead of getting added as separate Element my code is adding as SubElement

Tags: python, python-3.x, elementtree

I have sample xml file like below and I would like to add an Element `<item>DEV</item>` after `<item>Production</item>`

Before (Sample.xml)

```
<resource xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.android.com/apk" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.android">
    <string-array name="selectable_environment" ns1:ignore="InconsistenArray">
        <item>QA</item>
        <item>SIT</item>
        <item>Staging</item>
        <item>Production</item>
        <item>RQA</item>
        <item>PTE</item>
    </string-array>
<resource>
```

Expected output (Output.xml)

```
<resource xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.android.com/apk" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.android">
    <string-array name="selectable_environment" ns1:ignore="InconsistenArray">
        <item>QA</item>
        <item>SIT</item>
        <item>Staging</item>
        <item>Production</item>
        <item>DEV</item>
        <item>RQA</item>
        <item>PTE</item>
    </string-array>
<resource>
```

Here is my sample code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
mytree = ET.parse("Sample.xml")
root = mytree.getroot()
for child in root.iter('item'):
    if child.text == "Production":
        new = ET.SubElement(child,'item')
        new.text = "DEV"
mytee.write("Output.xml")
```

I am getting result as

```
<resource xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.android.com/apk" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.android">
    <string-array name="selectable_environment" ns1:ignore="InconsistenArray">
        <item>QA</item>
        <item>SIT</item>
        <item>Staging</item>
        <item>Production<item>DEV</item></item>
        <item>DEV</item>
        <item>RQA</item>
        <item>PTE</item>
    </string-array>
<resource>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I think that's supposed to be ```mytree.write(...)```

Comment: Afaik, you shouldn't use SubElement.  I think what you should do is try to insert a new element after the production element in the tree.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python ElementTree: How to add SubElement at VERY specific position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25824920/python-elementtree-how-to-add-subelement-at-very-specific-position)

Comment: If you're interested in trying lxml instead of ElementTree you could use xpath to target the "Production" item and then use the addnext() method to add a sibling. Let me know and I can add an example.

Comment: Thanks ewong and Daniel

Comment: @DanielHaley Can you please share some example on how to use lxml for adding a new element. I tried with solution @Pierre-Loic shared and it works fine but after adding new Element it does not create new line. 
`<item>DEV</item><item>RQA</item>`

Comment: @RR888 - I added an answer, but there's a little extra work to get the new `item` on its own line.

Comment: @DanielHaley This is awesome :)....thank you very much

Comment: @DanielHaley Can we add indentation to the Elements. The requirement is to have <item>...</item> with 4 indentations. Right now i see with only 2 for all elements. The original file has 4 but this script after adding new Element, it is changing the indentation to 2.

Comment: @RR888 - That should probably be a new question, but I updated my answer anyway.

Comment: @DanielHaley Thank you for that :) Learnt something new

Comment: @DanielHaley Unfortunately my office machines does not have the lxml version 4.5. They are running on very old version 3.2. Is there any other way i can fix the problem.

Comment: @RR888 - The only other way I can think of is to process the serialized XML as a string and manually increase the indent by replacing every set of 2 leading spaces with 4.

Comment: @DanielHaley Thank you. I did the same thing finally and it worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you please share some example on how to use lxml for adding a new element. I tried with solution @Pierre-Loic shared and it works fine but after adding new Element it does not create new line.

Here's the core example using the `addnext()` method in lxml...

```py
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("input.xml")

try:
    target_elem = tree.xpath("./string-array/item[.='Production']")[0]
    new_elem = etree.fromstring("<item>DEV</item>")  # Could also construct a new Element and set .text.
    target_elem.addnext(new_elem)
except IndexError:
    print("Unable to find target element.")

tree.write("output.xml")
```

But as you'll see, this also outputs the new `item` on the same line as its sibling...

```xml
<resource xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.android.com/apk" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.android">
   <string-array name="selectable_environment" ns1:ignore="InconsistenArray">
       <item>QA</item>
       <item>SIT</item>
       <item>Staging</item>
       <item>Production</item><item>DEV</item>
       <item>RQA</item>
       <item>PTE</item>
   </string-array>
</resource>
```

This is purely formatting, but if you want to "reset" the pretty printing I'd suggest serializing the tree to a string, then parse that string using an XMLParser to strip all whitespace and then writing the new pretty printed tree to a file...

```py
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("input.xml")

try:
    target_elem = tree.xpath("./string-array/item[.='Production']")[0]
    new_elem = etree.fromstring("<item>DEV</item>")  # Could also construct a new Element and set .text.
    target_elem.addnext(new_elem)
except IndexError:
    print("Unable to find target element.")

# "Reset" pretty printing and write to file.
parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
etree.ElementTree(etree.fromstring(etree.tostring(tree),
                                   parser=parser)).write("output.xml",
                                                         pretty_print=True)
```

output...

```xml
<resource xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.android.com/apk" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.android">
  <string-array name="selectable_environment" ns1:ignore="InconsistenArray">
    <item>QA</item>
    <item>SIT</item>
    <item>Staging</item>
    <item>Production</item>
    <item>DEV</item>
    <item>RQA</item>
    <item>PTE</item>
  </string-array>
</resource>
```

> Can we add indentation to the Elements. The requirement is to have `<item>...</item>` with 4 indentations. Right now i see with only 2 for all elements. The original file has 4 but this script after adding new Element, it is changing the indentation to 2.

If you're using lxml 4.5 or greater, you can use the [indent() function](https://lxml.de/apidoc/lxml.etree.html#lxml.etree.indent)...

```py
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("input.xml")

try:
    target_elem = tree.xpath("./string-array/item[.='Production']")[0]
    new_elem = etree.fromstring("<item>DEV</item>")  # Could also construct a new Element and set .text.
    target_elem.addnext(new_elem)
except IndexError:
    print("Unable to find target element.")

# "Reset" pretty printing.
parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
new_tree = etree.ElementTree(etree.fromstring(etree.tostring(tree), parser=parser))
# Indent 4 spaces instead of the default 2.
etree.indent(new_tree, space="    ")
# Write to file.
new_tree.write("output.xml", pretty_print=True)
```

output...

```xml
<resource xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.android.com/apk" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.android">
    <string-array name="selectable_environment" ns1:ignore="InconsistenArray">
        <item>QA</item>
        <item>SIT</item>
        <item>Staging</item>
        <item>Production</item>
        <item>DEV</item>
        <item>RQA</item>
        <item>PTE</item>
    </string-array>
</resource>
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, you can collect the parent of the node with the text "Production". You need also to have the index of the node with the text "Production" : you can get it with the function `enumerate()`. You can code it like that :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
mytree = ET.parse("Sample.xml")
root = mytree.getroot()
for child in root.iter():
    for i, elt in enumerate(child.getchildren()):
        if elt.text == "Production":
            new = ET.Element('item')
            new.text = "DEV"
            child.insert(i+1, new)
mytree.write("Output.xml")
```

Comment: I See the following results, how do we add a new line after inserting new Element

Comment: `<resource xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.android.com/apk" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.android">
    <string-array name="selectable_environment" ns1:ignore="InconsistenArray">
        <item>QA</item>
        <item>SIT</item>
        <item>Staging</item>
        <item>Production</item>
        <item>DEV</item><item>RQA</item>
        <item>PTE</item>
    </string-array>
<resource>`